# VS 2019 - Windows Application Packaging Project: Could not copy the file "...\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd" because it was not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, csproj

I have an existing solution for a UWP Windows Store app, and I recently needed to add Win32 desktop app capabilities to it. I reviewed the Microsoft documentation for adding a full trust executable and followed the example here: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/
After adding the Windows Application Packaging Project and adding my UWP app project as the entry point, I get this error while building:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4643,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\path\to\UWP\project\bin\x86\Debug\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd" because it was not found.
```

I notice that `WinMetadata\Windows.winmd` is normally included in the AppX folder when packaging the UWP app by itself, but it usually does not appear in the base `bin\x86\Debug` folder. If I remove almost all of the C# code referenced in my project, I am able to build and run the app. 
Why would the Windows Application Packaging project be looking for this file in `<UWP_Project>\bin\x86\Debug`?

UPDATE:
If I create a new blank UWP project and add it as a reference to the WAP project instead, I can confirm it builds fine. But if I then add in my other dependencies, nugets, and project references containing my UWP app's code, I get the behavior I described.

Most of the app's C# code is contained in shared projects (for portability). These shared projects only contain C# code. If I do the above steps, reproduce the error (missing `WinMetadata\Windows.winmd`) and then *remove* these shared project references containing the code (leaving all Nugets and other dependencies), it builds again! Obviously I need the code as part of the app..

I assume this file (`WinMetadata\Windows.winmd`) is added by default for UWP apps, so is there a particular thing I should be looking for, maybe in the build log, to see why this file would not be copied into that location?

Comment: Have you used UWP api in your desktop app, please check if there is yellow waring in the desktop app project reference?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I can confirm that the problem above occurs without the Win32 Desktop app added as a reference.

Comment: Could you share a code sample for us, I could not reproduce above with blank desktop-bridge app.